# QT nmake exception "Undefined Interface" at QTCharts "cartesianchartaxis_p.h"

Tags: c++, qt, visual-studio-2012, nmake, qtcharts

I'm trying to use QTCharts 2.1.0 for QT 5.4.1 version. I use opensource QT and tried to install QTCharts as the instructions shown in this [qtcharts github release-2.1.0 link](https://github.com/qt/qtcharts/tree/release-2.1.0)

I build without any problems but when I try to run it with nmake I get the exception shown belown and I genuinely have no idea about the reason. So, I'd appreciate any help. I'm using VS2012 x86 Native Tools Command Prompt btw.

**Exception:**

```
 C:\Qt\Qt5.4.1\5.4\msvc2012_opengl\bin\moc.exe -DUNICODE -DWIN32 -DQT_CHA
RTS_LIBRARY -DQT_BUILD_CHARTS_LIB -DQT_BUILDING_QT -D_CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS -D_
USE_MATH_DEFINES -DQT_NO_CAST_TO_ASCII -DQT_ASCII_CAST_WARNINGS -DQT_MOC_COMPAT
-DQT_USE_QSTRINGBUILDER -DQT_DEPRECATED_WARNINGS -DQT_DISABLE_DEPRECATED_BEFORE=
0x040800 -DQT_NO_EXCEPTIONS -DQT_NO_DEBUG -DQT_WIDGETS_LIB -DQT_GUI_LIB -DQT_COR
E_LIB -DNDEBUG -D_MSC_VER=1700 -D_WIN32 @.moc/release/mocinclude.tmp axis\cartes
ianchartaxis_p.h -o .moc\release\moc_cartesianchartaxis_p.cpp
axis\cartesianchartaxis_p.h(44): Error: Undefined interface
NMAKE : fatal error U1077: 'C:\Qt\Qt5.4.1\5.4\msvc2012_opengl\bin\moc.exe' : ret
urn code '0x1'
Stop.
NMAKE : fatal error U1077: '"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0
\VC\BIN\nmake.exe"' : return code '0x2'
Stop.
NMAKE : fatal error U1077: 'cd' : return code '0x2'
Stop.
NMAKE : fatal error U1077: 'cd' : return code '0x2'
Stop.
```

Answer (score 0):

Look at here! I had the same problem. In file `cartesianchartaxis_p.h` 44 line, its a declare of a interface `QGraphicsLayoutItem`. The compiler can not find the class. You can try to make the file `qgraphicslayoutitem.h` accessable. 
As I did, I include the absolute file path in the ahead of the file `cartesianchartaxis_p.h`,`#include "C:\Qt\Qt5.5.0\5.5\msvc2012\include\QtWidgets\qgraphicslayoutitem.h"`.In this way it worked well.
Xi wang ni neng kan de dong!!!!
                                                       --From a English fool